# Is it possible to prepend text to multiple lines

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to prepend text to my CSS to make it work in a specific div, but unfortunatly it's over 500 lines, so manually editing to add would be a pain and not worth it.

What I want to achieve (this is my css before using the sublime function (if it has one))

```css
.innerAll {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.layout-timeline ul.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
}
.layout-timeline ul.timeline > li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
.separator.bottom {
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
.separator {
    padding: 10px 0 3px 0;
    display: block;
}
.layout-timeline ul.timeline > li .date {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    left: -70px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

What I want to achieve:

```css
#timeline .innerAll {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#timeline .layout-timeline ul.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
}
#timeline .layout-timeline ul.timeline > li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
#timeline .separator.bottom {
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
#timline .separator {
    padding: 10px 0 3px 0;
    display: block;
}
#timeline .layout-timeline ul.timeline > li .date {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    left: -70px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

So with sublime is it possible to select all text and then prepend some? I can't ctrl + f to replace.

Comment: Are you prepending to every single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't ctrl + f to replace

No, because ctrl+f is "find". Use ctrl+h for replace, and

- with regex enabled
- replace `^[^\n]+ \{`
- with `#timeline $0`

Comment: No... I don't mean I don't know how. I mean it's not physically possible.

Comment: Your keyboard is missing an H? Find and replace works just find for me, if you "find" the right thing

Comment: @randommman: What do you mean by "it's not physically possible"? This solution will give you the exact results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to prepend literally every single selector? If so, search for

```
{
```

Since that is present in and only in the line where you want to prepend, then press alt+enter to select every found instance. Pos1 to go to the beginning of all those lines and type #timeline. Sublime is usually pretty smooth, but it might take some time to process that many selections all at once.

Edit: just remembered, if you don't want to prepend all selectors, but those that you do want prepended are all together, you can first select the entire block that contains those selectors and then search with the option "In selection" turned on (button two to the left of the search text field)

Comment: What do you mean by `Pos1`?

Comment: The key to jump to the beginning of the line, usually located in a block of six keys right above the arrow keys. Is it called something different on English keyboards? I thought "Position 1" should have been a safe bet.

Comment: "Home" on my keyboard. Watch out for its behaviour with word wrap switched off

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is any in sublime but considering you have installed php
run this script you will get what you need in this css_file_with_addition.css file at the same directory where  css_file_without_addition.css is present

```
$fp = fopen("css_file_without_addition.css", "r");
$fp_modify = fopen("css_file_with_addition.css","w+");

while($fst = fgets($fp)){

if(strpos($fst,"{")){
    $fst = "#timeline ".$fst;
}
fwrite($fp_modify,$fst);
fclose($fp);
fclose($fp_modify);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple and easy to understand method, but it is very effective;
[image]